# Can't get mouseover polygon to work with google maps - Uncaught Reference Error: google is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

New to coding and trying to build and application with google map feature utilizing polygons.  Have seen this question asked a few times but cannot seem to identify my issue.  The map initializes and polygons are created from defined locations.  I get an "uncaught reference error: google is not defined" when trying to utilize event listeners I am using to try to change the style of the polygon when it is hovered on.

```
var map;

// Map Display options
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 9,
    center: {lat: 42.05, lng: -70.25},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  });

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.   
  var cc_peaked_hill =  [
    {lat: 42.049803, lng: -69.970551},
    {lat: 42.048273, lng: -69.978790},
    {lat: 42.043684, lng: -70.046082},
    {lat: 42.043684, lng: -70.058441},
    {lat: 42.056940, lng: -70.085907},
    {lat: 42.070194, lng: -70.118179},
    {lat: 42.079369, lng: -70.156631},
    {lat: 42.049803, lng: -69.970551}
  ];

  // Construct the polygon.
  var cc_peaked_hill_billsPollygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: cc_peaked_hill,
    strokeColor: '#F7F8FF',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#4562A8',
    fillOpacity: 0.45,
    editable: false
  });

  // Build the Polygons
  polygons = cc_peaked_hill_billsPollygon.setMap(map);

  //Listen for when the mouse hovers over the polygon.
  google.maps.event.addListener(polygons, 'mouseover', function (event) {
      // Within the event listener, "this" refers to the polygon which
      // received the event.
      this.setOptions({
          strokeColor: '#00ff00',
          fillColor: '#00ff00'
      });
  });

}
```

For some reason, I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Reference Error: google is not defined
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: you may have not included the plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you firstly do this:

```
polygons = cc_peaked_hill_billsPollygon.setMap(map);
```

Which is really just setting the `map` property on your polygon (in fact `setMap` doesn't return anything).  It doesn't give you a polygon.  You already have that, in the `cc_peaked_hill_billsPollygon` variable.

So when you try and setup the event listener, just use that.

And in fact you don't even need to call `setMap`.  Simply assign the map property at the time you create the polygon.

```
// Construct the polygon.
  var cc_peaked_hill_billsPollygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: cc_peaked_hill,
    strokeColor: '#F7F8FF',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#4562A8',
    fillOpacity: 0.45,
    editable: false,
    map: map   // Does the equivalent of `setMap(map)`
  });

  //Listen for when the mouse hovers over the polygon.
  google.maps.event.addListener(cc_peaked_hill_billsPollygon, 'mouseover', function (event) {
      // Within the event listener, "this" refers to the polygon which
      // received the event.
      this.setOptions({
          strokeColor: '#00ff00',
          fillColor: '#00ff00'
      });
  });
```

PS: there's an even neater way you can add your event listener.  Just do:

```
  cc_peaked_hill_billsPollygon.addListener('mouseover', function (event) {
      // Within the event listener, "this" refers to the polygon which
      // received the event.
      this.setOptions({
          strokeColor: '#00ff00',
          fillColor: '#00ff00'
      });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I removed the following:  // Build the Polygons
  polygons = cc_peaked_hill_billsPollygon.setMap(map);

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I followed your recommendations by removing polygons = cc_peaked_hill_billsPollygon.setMap(map); and adding map: map to the var cc_peaked_hill_billsPollygon.  I unfortunately am still getting the reference error: google is not defined even when user the neater event listener.  Any other ideas?